# What is the purpose of \l_char_special_seq in expl3?

Tags: expl3, catcodes

When looking for a `\dospecials` version in `expl3`, I came across the predefined sequence `\l_char_special_seq` for which the documentation says:

> Used to track which tokens will require special handling when working with verbatim-like material at the document level as they are not of categories *letter* (catcode 11) or *other* (catcode 12). Each entry in the sequence consists of a single escaped token, for example `\\` for the backslash or `\{` for an opening brace. Escaped tokens should be added to the sequence when they are defined for general document use.

However, this sequence is never used in the `expl3` code, so I'm wondering about its purpose. (There's a similar sequence `\l_char_active_seq` which seems to be used when writing to files.)

What's the dedicated use case of `\l_char_special_seq`? Should it be used in conjunction with `\seq_map_inline:Nn` or similar functions in place of the old `\dospecials`?

Answer (score 2):

As the description says, the `special` sequence is for anything that is not catcode 11/12, whereas the `active` one is for only those chars which are catcode 13.

Since these were introduced, we have reworked some aspects of handling of active chars. It's possible that we may remove one or both of these sequences: ideas in `l3cctab` likely make them obsolete. However, at present that has not happened.

As for many aspects of `expl3`, they are there *for others to use* as much as for the team. I would use them *only* with a sequence mapping.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that these sequences are a hint from a class or document writer to package writers on how certain characters should be treated if handled in verbatim-like code? The thing that confuses me is that they are meant to be local variables, not global ones. As a package writer, should I rely on that sequence to be complete when I need to remap catcodes?

Comment: The are local as catcodes can be _set_ in a group: one has to know the current values. We do our best to populate them, but of course if someone just does `\catcode whatever = whatnot`, we are in trouble.